# Calculate total duration of all calls in Android

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager, calllog

How to trace starting time and ending time of all call log and show total duration in Android?

Here is my code which I have used for total duration but it is not working:

```
if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
        TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
        TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //Total time talked =
            long total_time = end_time - start_time;
            //Store total_time somewhere or pass it to an Activity using intent
        }
    }
}>
```

Comment: what's the value of total_time?

Comment: have you considered reading the duration from the CallLog.Calls API? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html

Comment: hello @iamnoten value of total time should be in minutes and one more thing it should be subtraction of start time and end time of call, both call incoming and outgoing.